# custom header view not heighlight when drawerlayout open

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am using drawerlayout with custom view instead of toolbar,when drawer open custom view faded,but i want when drawerlayout open custom header view should not fade.

my view look now  [drawerlayout screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PfGa.png)

### mainactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header_view"
            layout="@layout/layout_header_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer_RL"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_view">

        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer_RL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_footer_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_List"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="5">


        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_List1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You can customize toolbar the way you want.

Comment: but i want custom view on toolbar,is it possible,i just try but same thing happen

Comment: here is my code

Comment: Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
        LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(BaseActivity.this);
        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_header_view, null);
        toolbar.addView(mCustomView);

Comment: I am using BaseActivityConcept, common Navigation Drawer technique pls reply

Comment: you can inflate this layout in base activity and can use it for other. No need to create custom view.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use toolbar instead of using header view.
```

toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <include layout="@layout/textview"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

textview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

your layout

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <include layout="@layout/layout_toolBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/footer_RL"
                >

            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer_RL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <!--<include-->
                    <!--layout="@layout/layout_footer_view"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_List"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:weightSum="5">


            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_List1"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```